# Activated Route URL Always Empty

Tags: angular, angular-router

Consider the following service,

```
@Injectable()
export class SagasService {
    constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute, private router : Router ){
    router.events
        .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart)
        .subscribe(e=>{
            route.url.subscribe(a=>console.log(a[0].path));
        });
    }
}
```

Every time the route changes, the `console.log()` triggers. But, no matter what the route, the value is always `""` (empty string).

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The definition of the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) is:

> Contains the information about a route associated with a component loaded in an outlet. An ActivatedRoute can also be used to traverse the router state tree.

That means that if you inject it in the service, you will get the `ActivatedRoute` from the AppComponent. Which would always have the path of `""`.

You can traverse the  state tree to find the last activated route like

```
this.router.events.pipe(
 filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
 map(() => this.activatedRoute),
 map(route => {
   while (route.firstChild) {
    route = route.firstChild;
   }
   return route;
  }),
  map(route => route.url)
 )
.subscribe( // ... do something with the url)
```

Comment: By using this answer, I was able to get my code to work! Kudos! Still, I don't understand why they made this design choice

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. `router` is not an observable and `activatedRoute` is never declared anywhere

Comment: Should be router.events. Fixed it. The answer assumes that you inject both the Router and the ActivatedRoute in the contructor.

Answer (score 16):

if you want to get the current URL, you can import the location import from angular/common as below

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

constructor(public location: Location ){ }

let currentUrl = this.location.path();
```

can be used in NavigationEnd subscriber

Comment: This is pretty awesome, but will this also get the params?

Comment: I am not sure whether it will get params, if it is not  u can use activated route in the next line to achieve the params

Comment: The url string from Location is not the same thing as the `UrlSegments[]` you would get from the `ActivateRouted` url property

Answer (score 3):

The angular router sends the parameters to target component, and only it will be able to read those parameters.

However, you can use router events in service like RoutesRecognized to access the url parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of answers, but I think the following code might be a more 'polished' solution.
All required values can be mapped in a way to fit your needs.

```
export class AppTitleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
public id$ : Observable<number>;

constructor(
    private _router: Router,
    private _activatedRoute : ActivatedRoute
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.id$ = GeneralFunctions.GetRouteValues({
        router : this._router,
        activatedRoute : this._activatedRoute
    }).pipe(
      map( d => +d.params.id)
    )
}
```

With the following function ready for use:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Params, Data } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class GeneralFunctions {
   constructor() {
   }

   public  static GetRouteValues({router, activatedRoute}: { 
        router: Router; 
        activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute; 
    })  : Observable<{
        route: ActivatedRoute;
        params: Params;
        data: Data;
    }> {
        return router
            .events
            .pipe(
                filter(e => 
                e instanceof NavigationEnd
            ),          
                map(() => 
                activatedRoute
            ),          
            map(route => {
                if (route.firstChild) {
                    route = route.firstChild;
                }
                return route;
            }),
            filter(route => 
                route.outlet === 'primary'
            ),
            map(route => { return  {
                route : route,
                params : route.snapshot.params,
                data : route.snapshot.data
            }})
        );
   }
}
```